# Как присвоить элемент(file) input.files к другому(скрытому) input?

Tags: javascript, form, input

```
function showValue (files) {
        if (files.length > 0) {
            for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                let data = new FormData()
                data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                let item = document.createElement('div')
                let newInput = document.createElement('input')
                let newLabel = document.createElement('label')
                let button = document.createElement('button')
                button.addEventListener('click', handleDeleteInput, false)
                newInput.type = 'file'
                newInput.files = files // так работает, но он копирует весь массив files, а мне нужен только один элемент из массива 
                newInput.files = files[i] // так не работает, выдает ошибку Failed to set the 'files' property on 'HTMLInputElement': Failed to convert value to 'FileList'.
                console.log(newInput.files, input.files)
                newInput.id = files[i].name
                newLabel.for = files[i].name
                newLabel.innerHTML = files[i].name
                item.append(newInput, newLabel, button)
                dragList.appendChild(item)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `newInput.files = [files[i]]`. А вам точно надо создать много newInput? Почему бы не создать один и в него присвоить много файлов?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko имеено по одному файлу:) Не помогло, такая же ошибка Failed to set the 'files' property on 'HTMLInputElement': Failed to convert value to 'FileList'.

Comment: Прямого пути оказывается нету, а что вы хотите этим добиться?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko хочу сделать загрузку файлов, с возможность добавляения и удаления файлов, так как дефолтное поведение удаляет предыдущий input.files, пришлось создать дополнительные чтобы впихивать в них файл, тем самым можно спокойно удалять и добавлять файлы, но вот одна проблема что не могу впихивать именно один файл.

Comment: Ну так бы сразу и сказали) Для добавления и удаления файлов вам не нужно создавать `input`. Скопируйте выбранные файлы в массив, массив показываете, удаляете из него. При каждом добавлении в input - добавляете в ваш массив, отображает... и Тд.